# Symfony (strict) validation

Tags: php, symfony

Собственно вопрос, условно создается валидатор который принимает объект

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php

// ...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $name;
}
```

Далее все точно по ману

```
$author = new Author();

// ... do something to the $author object

$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($author);
```

Можно ли заставить валидатор ругаться каждый раз, когда в запросе приходят поля которых не ожидают? Например кроме имя передали фамилию, в поведении "по умолчанию", фамилия будет проигнорирована, а мне нужна ошибка (строгий валидатор).